# tengo un problema con una aplicación MVC para pasar parámetros de una vista a otra

Tags: html, mvc

Estoy pasando los parámetros de una vista a otra pasando por el controlador, espero ser muy claro.

En la vista realizo esto es de la siguiente manera:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Remision","Home", new { consecut = 4})">Remisión</a>
```

En el controlador simplemente hago lo siguiente:

```
    public ActionResult Remision(int consecut)
    {
        ViewData["consecutivo"] = consecut;
        return View();
    }
```

Y hasta ahí todo funciona bien y no tengo problema pero en donde tengo la variable `consecut = 4` en realidad no debe ser `4` debe tomar el valor de un `input`, sin embargo no encuentro la manera para poder hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si deseas pasar el valor de un input como parámetro en el enlace de tu vista MVC, puedes utilizar JavaScript para obtener el valor del input y construir dinámicamente la URL del enlace.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo:

1- Agrega un id al input que contiene el valor que deseas pasar como parámetro:

```
<input type="text" id="consecutivoInput" />
```

2- Modifica el enlace en tu vista para que llame a una función JavaScript y pase el valor del input como parámetro:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="enviarRemision()">Remisión</a>
```

3- Agrega el siguiente código JavaScript en tu vista para obtener el valor del input y redirigir a la acción del controlador con el valor como parámetro:

```
<script>
  function enviarRemision() {
    var consecutivo = document.getElementById('consecutivoInput').value;
    location.href = '@Url.Action("Remision", "Home")' + '?consecut=' + consecutivo;
  }
</script>
```

En este código, obtenemos el valor del input utilizando `document.getElementById('consecutivoInput').value` y luego concatenamos el valor a la URL de la acción del controlador utilizando `@Url.Action`. El resultado es una redirección a la acción del controlador con el parámetro adecuado.

Recuerda que en tu controlador, la acción Remision debe recibir un parámetro consecut para recibir el valor pasado en la URL.

Comment: Usar chatGPT para responder está prohibido. Tu cuenta podría ser sancionada.

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras ¿cómo sabes que ha  usado chatGPT?

Comment: @A.Cedano no lo divulgaré aquí, pero pasa por el historial del usuario. Además, 6 minutos pasaron entre la publicación de la pregunta y la formulación de la respuesta.

Comment: Ok @MauricioContreras, pues [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/593535/29967) suena mucho a chatGPT. Curiosamente, no sabe distinguir entre una propiedad y un método.

Comment: @Zerotet Gracias por tu contribución, te recomiendo leer [este artículo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido).